# C++ program times out on ODE

Tags: c++, multithreading, ide

I have written a program that times out on both coliru as well as on [ideone](https://ideone.com/zsQBQJ).

The program calls **call_once**() in a multi-threaded environment:
-- **EDIT** -- : **source code added**

```
** 
    call_once_xcp.cpp

    Demonstrate that if the first call to the call_once() function
    is unsuccessful, it will invoke a subsequent functionality.

**/

#include <mutex>        /// once_flag, call_once()
#include <thread>       /// thread
#include <exception>        /// runtime_error
#include <iostream>     /// cout

using namespace std;

once_flag of;

/// declarations ...
void func_call_xcp();   /// will call func_xcp()
void func_xcp();    /// will throw
void func_call_OK();    /// will call func_OK()
void func_OK();     /// won't throw


int main()
{
   thread t1 {func_call_xcp};
   t1.join();

   thread t2 {func_call_OK};
   t2.join();

   thread t3 {func_call_OK};
   t3.join();
}


/// will call func_xcp()
void func_call_xcp()
{
   try
   {
      call_once(of, func_xcp);
   }
   catch (exception& e)
   {
      cout << "exception: " << e.what()
           << endl;
   }
}


/// will call func_OK()
void func_call_OK()
{
   call_once(of, func_OK);
}


void func_xcp()     /// will throw
{
   cout << "** func_xcp()" << endl;

   throw runtime_error 
       {"error in func_xcp()"};
}


void func_OK()      /// won't throw
{
   cout << "** func_OK()" << endl;
}
```

The message is:

```
Time limit exceeded #stdin #stdout 5s 4364KB
```

Is there any way to *increase* the time limit on either of these **ODE**s (online development environments) or on any other ODE?

Comment: Instead of increasing time blindly.. rather find out what is causing the timeout

Comment: @B001, The [program](https://ideone.com/zsQBQJ) is quite simple. I'm not sure if its speed can be improved.

Comment: came here for an ordinary differental equation :(* anyhow I dont understand how `call_once` is supposed to be related to a timeout

Comment: Playing around with it a bit, it's pretty clear that the timeout is happening because of the exception handling, and not call_once() by itself. I'm not sure what the flags used on GCC are on ideone, but if it's not using optimization, it's conceivable that unwinding the STL's template mess would be heavy,

Comment: On ideone you can go to options at the bottom and increase limit to 15s

Comment: @KillzoneKid, which option (link) are you referring to?

Comment: @SSteven `more options` link left of `Run` button. It opens up time limit option under `enter input` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if the question is to find an online IDE that will run this code, try looking at Online GDB. Seems to be running it fine:

https://onlinegdb.com/rydvS9pTM

Also runs fine on a local host like MSVC 2015.

Comment: a local host would work fine, since there would be no time limit there. Seems like `onlne GDB` either doesn't have any time limit or the time limit is more generous.